# QGIS Map Done Need to publish

Tags: qgis

I am finished with my QGIS mapping project and now I want to save it and be able to view it from desktop only.

I am not wanting to publish this map to the internet and I do not want the other users on these particular computer to be able to modify/edit this map only view.

So the question is how would one go about doing this. Do I need a special "Map Viewer" to be able to do this?

Comment: Would you like to restrict users to change your data using it in QGIS? Or would you like to protect your vector/raster data to be copied/reused? Would you like to allow users to query attributes?

Comment: This particular map has a county wide personal information such as: Name, Address, Phone Number, XY Cord of residential and commercial buildings etc. This will be used by Fire/ Emergency Services. This can not be used/viewed by the "General Public" I would like for the services to be able to view the map data in a mapping program, but not be able to edit/copy etc.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Print Composer` to set your map layout in `QGIS` and export it into `pdf` or any other format you want.
You can try this [guide](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html)

Comment: I suppose a georeferenced raster is better  then PDF. It can be loaded into GIS software, can be displayed overlaying other data, etc.

Comment: He wants to only allow others to be able to view the data, a georeferenced raster might not work for that, though I'm not sure.@Zoltan Is it possible to make the raster view only?

Comment: This particular map has a county wide personal information such as: Name, Address, Phone Number, XY Cord of residential and commercial buildings etc. This will be used by Fire/ Emergency Services. This can not be used/viewed by the "General Public" I would like for the services to be able to view the map data in a mapping program, but not be able to edit/copy etc